# Dotnetcore container errors on startup asking if I mean to run SDK commands

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, docker-for-windows

I'm creating a simple dotnetcore 2.0 application and I want to containerize it. The idea being this container will run once on deployment to do some application configuration tasks.

At present, the code just does this...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

The docker file looks like this...

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "consoleapp.dll"]
```

I hit F5 in Visual Studio 2017 and I can see by doing a `docker image ls` command that the container exists.

I then attempt to run the container as follows:

`docker run consoleapp: dev`

I now get the error:

```
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

My thinking on this is that because I am using a runtime image to base my image on, I should be able to *somehow* start my application. I'm guessing the error here is that `dotnet` which forms part of my entry point is part of the dotnet SDK and hence is not in my base image.

Should I base this container on a non-runtime version of the dotnet core?

Answer (score 4):

One reason why you can see this error message is when the argument passed to `dotnet` is unknown.

The `runtime` doesn't recognize the argument you are passing to it and wonder if you perhaps should be using the `sdk` instead.

Make sure the name of the dll and the path to it are correct in:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "consoleapp.dll"]
```

Also, make sure the `COPY` instruction works as expected.

In your example it's picking files from the `obj/Docker/publish` folder. The output ready to be executed should come out of the `bin` folder instead.
If you are using the published version, make sure to run `dotnet publish` before creating the container. Or restore/build/publish when creating the image.

Remember the dll would have to end up exactly at the `WORKDIR`. In your case: /app
Unless you provide the path to `dotnet`

I've created a [basic working sample on Github](https://github.com/bruno-garcia/so-46654574):

Answer (score 0):

Create an app:

```
dotnet new console -o myApp
cd myApp/
dotnet publish -o publish -r linux-x64
# add docker file (see below)
docker build . -t myapp:latest
docker run --rm myapp:latest
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2-runtime
WORKDIR /opt/myapp
ADD publish .
ENV PATH="/opt/myapp:${PATH}"
CMD ["myApp"]
```